# For loop for counting approximation of pi in C

Tags: c, loops, pi, approximation

My program am I am trying to make is supposed to approximate pi using C using the series pi = 4 * (1 - (1/3) + (1/5) - (1/7) + (1/9) - (1/11) ...)  and so on.

Now, from the command line, the program must input the amount of terms to approximate out to, for example, if someone enters 5 from the command line the estimation would go out to (1/9).

The problem is that my output always yields zero, and I cannot determine the logical error I've made. I believe it is a for loop problem though.

One other note, I am using C, not C++.

My code is:

```
/*
Finding pi of an infinite series
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  //need to get input for amount of terms

    int i, pi;

    pi = 0;
    i = 0;
    double neg;  //neg to make a number negative

    neg = -1;       

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        pi = pi + pow(neg, i)*(1/((2*i)-1));
        i = i + 1;
    }

    printf("The approximation of pi is: %lf", pi);

    return 0;    
}
```

Note: for some reason it's not showing the libraries I'm including on Stack Overflow.  I did include the libraries, I'm not that dumb.

Comment: This is getting to be a common problem lately.

Comment: You have no reason to use `pow` here, you can just `neg *= -1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(1/((2*i)-1))
```

The above statement is an integer, since i is an integer. Integers don't have fractional parts, so this will always be zero. Since anything times zero is still zero, pi will remain zero.

You should change to doubles or floats to get a fractional answer.

Answer (score 4):

`argc` is the number of arguments. The contents of the arguments is stored in `argv`. The first argument (`argv[0]`) is the name of your program; if argc indicates it, the number you want is stored as a string in `argv[1]`.

```
int iterations = atoi(argv[1]);  /* convert string to integer */

for(i = 1; i < iterations; i++){
   /* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the code as below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  //need to get input for amount of terms
  int i, ncount;

   double neg, pi;  //neg to make a number negative
   pi = 0;
   neg = -1;

   ncount = atoi(argv[1]);

   for(i = 1; i < ncount; i++){
    pi = pi + pow(neg, (double)i)*(1.0/((2.0*(double)i)-1));
    i = i + 1;
   }

   printf("The approximation of pi is: %lf", pi);
   return 0;
}
```

you have to take argv value not argc to find count.  You have to convert pi value to double.